# Update the table column on the basis of another table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two database

```
Database ABC
table Client
|ClientId | ClientName | ScanId | NonScanId |
|1001     | Temp Client| NULL   | NULL      |
|1002     | ABC Client | NULL   | NULL      |
|1003     | 1234 Client| NULL   | NULL      |
|1004     | XYZA Client| NULL   | NULL      |

Database XYZ
table Client
|ClientId | ClientName          | IsScan| data      |
|1        | Temp Client Scan    | 1     | 1TCS      |
|2        | ABC Client Non-Scan | 0     | ACNS      |
|3        | 1234 Client Non Scan| 0     | 1CNS      |
|4        | XYZA Client Scan    | 1     | XYCS      |
```

Now, I need to update the ScanId and NonScanId in the Client table of database ABC on the basis of IsScan and ClientName of database XYZ. As the ClinetName is not the same I need to trim the Scan or Non Scan/Non-Scan from the client name to match.

So the required updated Client table of database ABC would be:

```
|ClientId | ClientName | ScanId | NonScanId |
|1001     | Temp Client| 1TCS   | NULL      |
|1002     | ABC Client | NULL   | ACNS      |
|1003     | 1234 Client| NULL   | 1CNS      |
|1004     | XYZA Client| XYCS   | NULL      |
```

Comment: How are you planning to join both table `ClientID` or `ClientName`?

Comment: I am planning to join by ClientName, but as the client name is different I need to trim the Scan or Non-Scan to join both table

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server 2017 onwards, then you can use the below code snippet to trim the unwanted text:

```
SELECT TRIM('#Scan' FROM ClientName) AS TrimmedString;
```

You can also use REPLACE for removing the unwanted text:

```
SELECT REPLACE(ClientName,'Scan','');
```

Comment: I am using SQL server 2015

Comment: You can use replace, the second snippet can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when to remove `Scan` and `Non Scan` then you can perform the join.
After joining 2 tables you can again use `case when` to create 2 columns with `data`

```
SELECT A.CLIENTID,
       A.CLIENTNAME,
       CASE
           WHEN B.ISSCAN = 1 THEN B.DATA
           ELSE NULL END AS SCANID,
       CASE
           WHEN B.ISSCAN = 0 THEN B.DATA
           ELSE NULL END AS NONSCANID
FROM ABC A
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT CLIENTID,
           CASE
               WHEN ISSCAN = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(CLIENTNAME, 1,LEN(CLIENTNAME) -5)
               ELSE SUBSTRING(CLIENTNAME, 1, LEN(CLIENTNAME) -9)
           END AS CLIENTNAME,
           ISSCAN,
           DATA
   FROM XYZ ) B ON A.CLIENTNAME = B.CLIENTNAME
```

**Output:**

```
|ClientId | ClientName | ScanId | NonScanId |
|1001     | Temp Client| 1TCS   | NULL      |
|1002     | ABC Client | NULL   | ACNS      |
|1003     | 1234 Client| NULL   | 1CNS      |
|1004     | XYZA Client| XYCS   | NULL      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
select c.*, 
       (case when x.IsScan = 1 then x.data end) as scanid,
       (case when x.IsScan = 0 then x.data end) as nonscanid,
from abc.client c left join
     xyz.client x
     on x.client_name like c.client_name + ' %';
```

This readily translates to an `update`:

```
update c 
    set scanid = (case when x.IsScan = 1 then x.data end),
        nonscanid = (case when x.IsScan = 0 then x.data end)
from abc.client c join
     xyz.client x
     on x.client_name like c.client_name + ' %';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for CTE based update statement as given below:

```sql
;WITH CTE_XYZ AS
(
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(clientName,'Non-Scan',''),'Scan','') AS ClientName, data
FROM xyz..Client
WHERE IsScan = 1
)
UPDATE tgt
SET ScanId = src.data
FROM abc..Client as tgt
INNER JOIN CTE_XYZ as src
ON tgt.ClientName = src.ClientName
```